# Schaum's Outlines Differential Geometry Problem 4.35

Tags: differential-geometry

Show that the curve $x=(t)e_1+((1+t)/t)e_2+((1-t^2)/t)e_3$ lies in a plane.

Comment: Readers may respond more aptly if you include enough context for your perspective to be understood.  How would you attack such a problem?

Comment: Compute the [torsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_of_a_curve). If it is $0$, then the curve stays in a plane; if not, then it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure they want you to compute the Frenet-Serrat frame and show that the torsion is $0$. I will not do that. There is another way.

The curve can be expressed as 
$r(t) = \left(t,\; 1 + \dfrac 1t,\; \dfrac 1t - t \right)$

For reasons that should soon become obvious, the $1$ in $1+t$ is in the way. So

$r(t) - (0,1,0) = \left(t,\; \dfrac 1t,\; \dfrac 1t - t \right)$

Now we search for a constant direction $(u,v,w)$ that is orthogonal to 
$r(t) - (0,1,0)$.

\begin{align}
   (u,v,w) \circ (r(t) - (0,1,0)) = 0 \\
   tu +  \dfrac 1t v +  \left(\dfrac 1t - t\right)w &= 0 \\
   t(u-w) + \dfrac 1t(v+w) &= 0\\
\end{align}

A solution is $(u,v,w)=(1,-1,1)$.

So $(r(t) - (0,1,0)) \circ (1,-1,1) = 0$

You can interpret this to mean that $r(t)$ lies in the plane containing the point $(0,1,0)$ and perpendicular to the vector
$\langle 1, -1, 1\rangle$. That is the plane $x-y+z = -1$.

### CHECK

$$ x-y+z =
   t - \left(1 + \dfrac 1t \right) + \left(\dfrac 1t - t \right) = -1$$